# Automatically verifying an OpenVPN configuration file

Tags: openvpn

I'd like to somehow verify automatically that a text file is indeed an OpenVPN configuration file. I don't need to know that it's fully correct, i only want to check that it's a config file intended for OpenVPN and not someone's /etc/passwd uploaded by mistake.

The openvpn doc doesn't seem to have any option related to my goal.

Anyone can point me to a ready made solution for that, if one exists?

Comment: Well extract all the valid config options from the man page.  Then write a script that verifies each line starts by either a comment or one of the valid options.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to avoid and sort of what I'll do if there is no existing solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess searching for this three pairs as the first two tokens on the same line should do:

- `dev ...`
- `proto ...`
- `cipher ...`

This one-liner does the trick:

```
perl -wanle'$h{$F[0]}=$F[1] if scalar @F>1; END {if ($h{dev} && $h{proto} && $h{cipher}) {print "ok";} else {print "not ok"; exit 1;}}' < the_file
```

`the_file` at the end is the file to check. The result is either:

- `ok` and exit code 0
- `not ok` and exit code 1

The code takes every line and assigns the second token in the line to a hash keyed with the first token if there are at least two tokens. At the end it checks for the presence of the keys `dev`, `proto` and `cipher`. For checking files in bulk the code should be optimised.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the lines that seem to be mandatory in any openvpn config file. I've never set up a vpn, i just need to shuffle some config files around. It will be python code, but that's my problem now ;)

Answer (score 0):

`cat [client_config_file].ovpn | sed '1,/<cert>/d;/<\/cert>/,$d' | openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /etc/openvpn/ca.crt`

ca.crt = public certificate file of the openvpn server CA (certificate authority)

Thanks for: https://gist.github.com/dleonard00/fa482b4e803bf1f905526275c116c6d8